# Come back to a chat room after leaving?

Tags: support, chat

If I'm in a chat room because an SO comments discussion got moved to chat, and I have to leave but I want to come back to that discussion later, does this happen the same way as if I were to leave a comments discussion--that is, close my browser, and then next time I log in to SO I'll see a notification indicating whether or not the other person has responded to my last chat message?  I'm trying to figure out how to make sure that I can continue the discussion the next time I'm back online.

Comment: Yes, you should have a notification if someone responds. (I have in the past anyways). The conversation isn't immediately ended if you leave it.